# User must interact with document first... cant play sound in my electronjs app

Tags: electron, chromium

I'm using electronjs to run my react app. My app plays a sound when certain values are met on my database. My issue is I'm getting: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. I understand this would be an issue in chrome but I figured this would not be an issue in electron using chromium. What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your main.js file -

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('autoplay-policy', 'no-user-gesture-required');
```

This disables the auto play policy of chromium browser